# Add grouped percentiles to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to figure out the percentile of each row of a dataframe within a given group. For a toy example, consider this dataset of athletes from different sports.

```
pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Joe", "Bob", "Susan", "Kate", "Sam", "Shawn"], 
          "sport": ["hockey", "hockey", "hockey", "baseball", "baseball", "baseball"],
         "points": [1,2,3,1,4,9]})
```

I want to compare the scoring activity of each athlete to athletes from the same sport. It wouldn't be fair to compare baseball and hockey players directly, so I want to see where each hockey player falls compared only to other hockey players. Here's the desired output.

```
pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Joe", "Bob", "Susan", "Kate", "Sam", "Shawn"], 
          "sport": ["hockey", "hockey", "hockey", "baseball", "baseball", "baseball"],
         "points": [1,2,3,1,4,9],
         "percentile": [0,.5,1,0,.5,1]})
```

My real dataset has thousands of groups and hundreds of thousands of rows.

Comment: Is the 5th item in `percentile` supposed to be `0.375`?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding about what exactly you want. @richardec downvoted all the answers just because they didn't match the values of your example but they do match your description. Your example is inconsistent -- what do you want as an output? Check out percentile description eg at [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html), namely the `kind` flag. What was given to you here is the `rank`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @MyWork You can't tell who downvoted, so don't say with certainty that I downvoted them when you have no way of telling beyond my comments. That said, I *did* downvote them, and I will be more than happy to reverse those votes when the anwers are corrected (not saying it's even the answerers' fault).

Answer (score 2):

```
df['percentile'] = df.groupby(['sport'])['points'].rank(pct=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    name     sport  points  percentile
0    Joe    hockey       1    0.333333
1    Bob    hockey       2    0.666667
2  Susan    hockey       3    1.000000
3   Kate  baseball       1    0.333333
4    Sam  baseball       4    0.666667
5  Shawn  baseball       9    1.000000
```

Comment: This doesn't match the OP's expected output...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no direct way of calculating percentiles. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601475/assigning-percentile-to-each-value-of-pandas-series) suggests using the [rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) method with `pct=True` to return percentiles, in combination with groupby, you get:

```py
df.groupby("sport")["points"].rank(pct=True)
```

resulting in

```
0    0.333333
1    0.666667
2    1.000000
3    0.333333
4    0.666667
5    1.000000
```

To assign that as a column, do:

```py
df['percentile'] = df.groupby("sport")["points"].rank(pct=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't match the OP's expected output...

Comment: @richardec see my comment to the question. The answer is answering what the question is asking for, just not matching the output because the output is a combination of many possibilities and IMO wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To have the expected output, use `groupby.rank` with rescaling:

Group size 3:

```
df['percentile'] = (df.groupby('sport')['points']
                      .rank(pct=True).
                      .sub(1/3).mul(3/2)
                    )
```

Generic:

```
df['percentile'] = (df.groupby('sport')['points']
                      .apply(lambda g: g.rank(pct=True)
                            .sub(1/len(g))
                            .mul(len(g)/(len(g)-1) if len(g)>1 else 0))
                     )
```

Output:

```
    name     sport  points  percentile
0    Joe    hockey       1         0.0
1    Bob    hockey       2         0.5
2  Susan    hockey       3         1.0
3   Kate  baseball       1         0.0
4    Sam  baseball       4         0.5
5  Shawn  baseball       9         1.0
```

Comment: How are the `1/3` and `3/2` determined here?

Comment: It's based on the group size, I'll update with a generic method